# How to theme form?

Tags: theming, forms, 8, ajax

I created a form in custom module,

Something like:

```
 $form['form00'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => 'dummy',
    );
$form['form01'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => 'dummy1',
    );
```

Questions are:

1. How do I theme the form? like wrapping them into some div, giving a class or id, and setting CSS property (e.g. float: left), etc.?
2. Can I control it from AJAX ? If yes,how?

Comment: You should read about render arrays and theme templates in drupal 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short story for or Q1: Wrap your form01 and form02 in a container:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!Element!Container.php/class/Container/8.2.x

Then add your classes with the #attribute variable like here:

```
'#attributes' => array(
    'class' => 'myclass',
  )
```

For Q2: It's a long story, read this: [Ajax API on Drupal](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.api.php/group/ajax/8.2.x)

Regards,

Rainer

Comment: for Q1. how do i define the CSS? once i define the class (or ID) ?

Comment: Create a css file with your styles and add it to the asset library of your module. Or attach the asset just to that form with the #attached library syntax.